# Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown, Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I am getting following error, while I run native iOS application within Xamarin.

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument
```

Stack Trace:

```
**  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:406 
at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:128 
at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
at TripplewinEWS.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00002] in /Users/yudizsolutions/Documents/projects/T/Git/TripplewinEWS/iOS/Main.cs:14 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
at TripplewinEWS.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00002] in /Users/yudizsolutions/Documents/projects/T/Git/TripplewinEWS/iOS/Main.cs:14 **
```

I unable to find what is actually causing error.
Help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show some codes ,and on which line is the error thrown .

Comment: It not showing which line of code is throwing error.
It throwing error at following line in "Main.cs" file

 UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");

Comment: Could you share your sample project,then i can test it.

Comment: Thanks @LeoZhu-MSFT for your approach.
The issue was with text of Label. White Space between text not allowed and caused error.

Comment: To resolve this I have just added \r\n where I required to keep white space in label text.